# Find the missing numbers in this constrained matrix/grid

Tags: combinatorics

The numbers 1 to 16 inclusive are arranged in this 4x4 matrix, such that no two numbers that are adjacent (horizontally, vertically *or diagonally*) that are consecutive, i.e. they must have a difference of at least 2.

\begin{bmatrix}11&?&?&?\\?&?&14&?\\?&6&?&?\\?&?&?&8\end{bmatrix}

What are the missing numbers?

Comment: Sorry there are many solutions to this.  The program that I wrote to analyse solutions has a bug in it!

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this seems too simple so I've probably missed something but I have one solution here

> | **11**  09  07  04 |
>  |  16 01 **14**  12 |
>  | 10  **06**  03 05 |
>  |  02  15 13  **08** |

My method is simple:

> Throw numbers in at random and swap one in the wrong place with another that wont cause another problem!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the diagonal constraint, I have added this now. 
 Therefore this is an invalid solution as several pairs of numbers diagonally are consecutive: (08 09), (11 12), (14 15)

Comment: Ah but you didn't say diagonally ;)

Comment: Apologies I have edited it now

Comment: Think I fixed it

Comment: Well done.  I thought there was only one solution but yours is correct also :).

Comment: Another one would simply be filling the blank square with the remaining odd numbers then the evens, from top left to bottom right. Then swap 7 and 13 for the only correction!

Comment: there are really quite a few.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possible answers if i understand the question correctly...

My example solution:

> **11** 09 12 05
>  13 16 **14** 07
>  01 **06** 04 02
>  03 10 15 **08**

How did i figure this out?

> Tried random numbers and it worked to my surprise :)

EDIT: Changed the numbers to match the new requirements
EDIT2: Added 'How did i figure this out?'

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the diagonal constraint, I have added this now.  Therefore this is an invalid solution as (05 06), and (15 16) are adjacent

Answer (score 0):

Like so many others before me, i have another answer, and i am sure there are more.

> |11 03 10 05 |
>  |01 16 14 07 |
>  |13 06 04 12 |
>  |09 15 02 08 |

How i got there

> I started at each corner and rotated each consecutive number to the alternate corner and one to the number's right. By placing them as far across, i assured there was no intersection against the rules

a few more

> |11 03 05 10 |
>  |01 16 14 07 |
>  |13 06 04 12 |
>  |09 15 02 08 | 
>
>
>  |11 03 05 10 |
>  |01 16 14 07 |
>  |13 06 04 12 |
>  |15 09 02 08 | 
>
>
>  |11 03 05 10 |
>  |01 16 14 07 |
>  |13 06 04 02 |
>  |15 09 12 08 |